# Ignore XML tags when tagging a file using Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: xml, stanford-nlp

I want to tag a text file that contains XML tags. However, when I use the Stanford tagger, everything gets annotated, even the XML tags. Is there a flag or some other option that allows me to specify that I only wanna have the text annotated and that the XML tags should be ignored? This is what I need to correct:

`<h>    NNP <h> O` -> Those tags should be ignored.

The TreeTagger ignores by default XML tags, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full pipeline instead.

Then use these annotators

`-annotators tokenize,cleanxml,ssplit, pos`

You can find all of the details at these links:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: Thank you but your answer is not the solution. First of all, I'm using the full pipeline. Second, `cleanxml` will delete all XML tags and that is not what I want. They must not be deleted, just ignored by the tagger.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what final result you want.  You will have to write some Java code if you want to operate on a token stream with XML tokens and only apply the part of speech tagger to the non-XML tokens.